# Flash Builder components not showing

Tags: flash, apache-flex, internet-explorer, google-chrome, flash-builder

I am trying to do a basic tutorial like MXML Application on Flash Builder 4.6 trial version

This is my code in deneme1.mxml 's Source part

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                label1.text="ateş buradaydı";
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:Button id="button1" x="319" y="176" label="Button" click="button1_clickHandler(event)" visible="true"/>
    <s:Label id="label1" x="222" y="176" text="Label"/>

</s:Application>
```

This is what I get in Desing mode

[image: This is how it looks in Design mode]

I am not doing very much action just trying to see something on the browser Chrome or IE9 but I only get a blank page.

As you can understand from my entrance of my question I am very newbie and don't know why the components are not showing.

What am I doing wrong?What am I supposed to do to make this work?

**EDIT:** I tried a sample code that I found [here](http://wonderfl.net/c/pZt8), copied and pasted the code it still does not show up on the browser.I downloaded the package added the mxml file to the project run it still no and the swf file that was generated does not show anything neither.However, the swf file comes with the package shows up.I can't think of any reason for this problem.Has anybody had a problem like this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exactly same situation. I tried all the above solutions with no luck.

My solution: I just created another application file from the project explorer. copy pasted the content from the existing application file(the one not working) I created when the project was created. Run and it came up. I know it is a very odd thing but this is what happened.

Answer (score 4):

I have exactly the same problem as you. I run the project on Google Chrome. However when I switch to IE it works fine. I guess there might be because of Chrome is preventing flash to run ?

You might want to check this out:

[Flash Builder 4.6 always shows blank html page on run in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064570/flash-builder-4-6-always-shows-blank-html-page-on-run-in-google-chrome)

[Flash Builder 4.5 won't run my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065202/flash-builder-4-5-wont-run-my-application)

**UPDATED:**
After browsing the solution, I have the Chrome problem solved by doing this:

-> type about:plugins in Chrome's address bar.

-> click details button on the upper right corner.

-> find the Flash plugin. In my case there are 2 components inside:

--> ...\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\27.0.1453.94\PepperFlash\pepflashplayer.dll

--> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash\NPSWF32_11_7_700_202.dll

-> disable the PepperFlash (the first one in my case).

-> reload/run your project again, you should be good now :)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working for me so there should be different reason.

Screen is small so I'm not sure if I see it good but it looks like you have "Deneme.mxml" as default application and I have no idea what you have there. If you want to start with deneme1.mxml right click it on Package Explorer (left side), choose "Set as Default Application" from menu and try now.

Comment: I was typing deneme1.html to browser's address bar.I also tried what you recommended but nothing changed.

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's a stupid question but did you Run Project?
(Run -> Run)

Comment: I did this right click on the project and Run as => Web Application, a couple times and also used the keyboard shortcut.I also put a div that contains text,"flash content is below" well div shows up but flash does not.

Comment: As I said before, can you RightClick on "Deneme.mxml" and choose "Set as Default Application" before you run project?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "deneme1.mxml". Ok so you said "(...) I also put a div that contains text (...)" What about starting your .swf file only ? Does it show anything? Or also blank scene ?

Comment: no .swf does not show the components, too.all I get is blank page when I open .html, and blank page(white flash) again when I open .swf.

Comment: Darn, I'm sure that code is fine. Can you try create new FlexProject (so you have only one *.mxml file) and paste code you post below? Just to make sure it's not caused by some rubbish compile settings or whatever...

Comment: I tried it now, still nothing.Thank you for your concern and time Evilguy.