# Flash Builder 4.5 won't run my application

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flash

I was running my application from Flash Builder 4.5.1 without any issues. (It is a Flex application that connects to .Net Web Services). However, *something* has changed recently in my configuration or project, because when I try to run the app with the play or debug button, I just get a grey screen. I can't even stop on any breakpoints.

Eventually (maybe 30 seconds), a message pops up like so: 'The Flash Builer failed to connect to the running application. Please make sure that you are running the debug version of Flash Player...'

- I definitely have latest version of Flash Debug Player installed (11.1.102.55). I have tried uninstalling it and re-installing it.
- I have tried cleaning and rebuilding my project.
- I have tried switching to a different workspace and back again.
- I have tried restarting the PC.

I am using the latest version of IE for testing.

I'm really stumped - has anybody got any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Which browser are you using to test?

Comment: @eterps - Good point - I'm using latest version of IE. Is there a way of changing which browser it tries to run in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried deleting the html-template folder? This has caused issues for me in the past.

After it's deleted, when you try to build you will have a compiler error/warning about the missing folder. Right click and 'rebuild'.

Comment: I 'thought' I'd already tried that, but evidently not, because it worked like a charm! Cheers for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with compatability between 64 bit IE9, the 64-bit flash player, and 32-bit debugger.  It seems like flash builder gets confused on which to use.  I haven't seen any decent resolution yet in the Adobe forums for this particular issue other than use a different browser for testing.

To switch browsers, go to Window > Preferences... > General > Web Browser in Flash Builder.  Select Firefox or Chrome.

In order to use Firefox, you need the Flash Debugger for Netscape compatable browsers installed.  You can get that from Adobe [here](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html).

To use Chrome, you need to replace the built in flash player that is installed with Chrome with the debug player.  Instructions from Adobe are [here](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/839/cpsid_83950.html).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but Sam's solution above worked for me.