# Flash Builder 4.6 always shows blank html page on run in Google Chrome

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.6

Flash Builder 4.6 always shows blank html page on run in Google Chrome.
I have tried everything but nothing works.

Kindly help.

Comment: One thing I have started to suspect is the problem (when a Flash problem only happens in Chrome) is the buggy Pepper Flash player that is now the default Flash Player in Chrome. You can try to disabling it by going to chrome://plugins -- you'll probably see several Flash plugins, just disable the Pepper Flash plugin.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Are you using RSL's, have you tested in other browsers? Are you using the default swfObject template? What flash player version do you have installed? Please elaborate your question so others will be able to help you better.

Comment: Try to compile something, if the compilation froze on about 50-60% then Chrome set non-debug version of the player, and you need to reset it or install new one and set it manually again from chrome://plugins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the solution, there is a security issue with chrome when html page runs on Chrome browser, So We need to set **use-network=false**  in Flex Compiler option in the Project Properties and everything of .swf backs on stage.

Answer (score 7):

Simple answer: Do not use Chrome for debugging Flash Builder projects.

For debugging, do this:

1. Go into the Debug Configurations (Run > Debug Configurations)
2. Find the configuration for the current project
3. Under "URL or path to launch", uncheck "Use default" and browse for
   the SWF (html is default). This will open the debug in the actually
   Flash Debug Player instead (as it happens in Flash CS)

or

1. Open your Flash Builder/Eclipse Preferences
2. Filter for "browser" and change any items that appear to another
   browser. I have had issues with Internet Explorer in the past, so I
   would stick to Firefox or Safari.

In my experience, this issue is almost always limited to the Debug Mode. I've experienced it once or twice with a Release Build, but the issue was, in the end, caused by the generated HTML, not by the SWF file itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just quickly test the actual SWF build, you could turn off the 'Generate HTML wrapper file' for you project. This will cause any debug or run to use the currently installed standalone flash player to be used for preview.

To do this - right click on your project in the package explorer window, choose properties, then Flex Compiler and then just un-tick 'Generate HTML wrapper file' under the HTML wrapper section